# What is the use-case for setting Kafka's replication factor to 0 in production?

Tags: apache-kafka

Is setting a replication factor of 0 invalid for a production environment or is there a use case where this makes sense?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Replication factor = 1 means there is a single copy of your data. If your broker fails then you lost all your data.

Replication factor = 2 means you have 2x copies of your data. So when 1 node fails then you ends up with a single copy of your data. When your 2nd node fails that your data is lost.

Replication factor = n means you have Nx copies of your data.

Replication factor = 0 does not makes any sense at all.

Comment: ^ This is the correct answer instead of the accepted one.
https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#replication


"Kafka is meant to be used with replication by default—in fact we implement un-replicated topics as replicated topics where the replication factor is one.

The unit of replication is the topic partition. Under non-failure conditions, each partition in Kafka has a single leader and zero or more followers. The total number of replicas including the leader constitute the replication factor."

Answer (score 4):

Replication factor must be larger than 0. Kafka does not allow users to create a topic with no replicas.